# Is it possible to calculate inversion and retrograde in guitar pro?

Tags: guitar-pro

I want to select a portion out of a guitar pro tab and i want to modify that with the inversion and the retrograde of that specific selection.

The inversion means that the order of the intervals based of the root note changes.

Retrograde means you play that portion backwards basically.

So is it possible to do it in Guitar Pro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sorry, none of those features are available in Guitar Pro.
There are not a lot of assistants to help creating tabs faster in GP, the only ones I found are for transposition (but only straight ones, by x semi-tones) and assistants for let rings and palm mutes.

But they are always looking for new feature ideas so you should suggest them (support@arobas-music.com). You won't have them soon though, if ever.